# What's the phrase that mean "eating without restriction"?

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

> She **let off loose** after marrying him and gained 40 pounds.

Is it let off loose or is it another phrase? I don't remember the phrase used to mean "eat without restriction". It was a slang I believe, but I forgot the phrase.

Comment: Maybe "let herself go"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used "let off loose", but there is "pigged out".

> He's been pigging out on snack food every chance he gets.

Obviously it's a reference to pigs that eat most anything any time.